# Laravel 2 роута ведущие на один контроллер и на один тот же метод

Tags: php, laravel

Есть  2 роута с разным url, но ведущие на один и тот же контроллер и метод, мне надо сделать так, если роут с url saveClient1  то из всех передавыемых параметров в request,
я заменяю допустим номер документа на 12345, а если роут с url saveClient2, я заменяю номер документа уже на другие цифры, допустим 85679

```html
    Route::post('/saveClient1', [CklController::class, 'saveClient']);
    Route::post('/saveClient2', [CklController::class, 'saveClient']);
    
  $document = 12345;
    
  $document = 85679;
```

то есть разные url, но ведут на один и тот же метод и контроллер, но в зависимости от url в request запросе я должен передавать разный номер документа,  номер документа прибит гвоздями, его значение меняться не будет, как это можно реализовать???????

Comment: что вам мешает определить этот номер внутри искомого метода  контроллера?

Comment: @teran метод ведь один, на два роута, только через условие,  если роут такой то улетает параметр с этим значение, если роут другой с другим значением

Comment: и? что мешает поименовать маршруты например, и сравнить имя потом? либо доп. параметром указать эти данные, а не "изменить в request" ?

Answer (score 1):

Вообще так не делается совсем. Это не расширяемо, дубль кода и прочие проблемы. Давайте разбираться. Во первых оставьте только 1 маршрут.

Для начала мы определяем какие документы могут быть. Так как номера документов фиксированы, то их кол-во будет ограничено и да же если появится новый мы не должны зависеть от этого (т.е. изменения кода должны быть минимальные). Допустим у нас 2 типа документа (пример абстрактный), док физ лица и док юр лица.

Создаём 3 класса. `Document`, `PhysicalDocument` и `LegalDocument`.

```
namespace App\Documents;

class Document
{
    public const NUMBER = null;
    // здесь будут общие методы для документов

    public function savePdf()...
    public function sendTo($connection)....
}

namespace App\Documents;

class PhysicalDocument
{
    public const NUMBER = 12345;
}


namespace App\Documents;

class LegalDocument
{
    public const NUMBER = 85679;
}
```

Следующим шагом необходимо добавить валидацию в наш метод `saveClient`. С помощью консоли создаем `request`. В нём с помощью `in` проверяем что документ может быть только нужных нам номеров. Этот вариант можно оставить, но чуть дальше сделаем по лучше.

```
class StoreClientRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'number' => [
                'required',
                'integer',
                Rule::in([PhysicalDocument::NUMBER, LegalDocument::NUMBER])
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

Далее идём в метод контроллера и пишем наш реквест. Валидация вызовется сама.

```
public function saveClient(StoreClientRequest $request)
{

}
```

Следующим шагом для избавления от `if/else` мы создадим сервис для управления документами, так как контроллер не должен знать о логике выполнения и обработки документов.

```
class DocumentService
{
    protected array $documents = [
        PhysicalDocument::NUMBER => PhysicalDocument::class,
        LegalDocument::NUMBER => LegalDocument::class
    ];

    public function getByID(int $number)
    {
        return $this->documents[$number] ? app($this->documents[$number]) : null;
    }

    public function getNumbers():array
    {
        return array_keys($this->documents);
    }

}
```

Данные сервис будет возвращать наш объект конкретного документа, а так же список нужных нам номеров. Далее для того чтобы не создавать объект каждый раз данного сервиса, создайте фасад который будет доступен во всех необходимых местах приложения

После создания фасада, заменяем наш "StoreClientRequest"

```
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'number' => [
                'required',
                'integer',
                Rule::in(DocumentService::getNumbers)
            ]
        ];
    }
```

И в методе контроллера добавляем наш сервис:

```
public function saveClient(StoreClientRequest $request)
{
    $document = DocumentService::getByID($request->number);

    if (!$document) return back()->withErrors("Документ не был найден");

    $client = new Client();
    $client = setDocument($document);

   // дальнейшие манипуляции для добавления клиента

   return $client;
}
```

В результате вы получаете более гибкую архитектуру, для её расширения создаете новый документ и прописываете в `DocumentService`. При этом каждый класс управляет только тем что нужно. А метод маршрута остаётся всего один

Comment: ему и в текущей реализации можно сделать один маршрут, если вынесет условные `1|2` в параметр. Так что не ясно, где вы в целом нашли дублирование кода.

Comment: там задача скорее всего тривиальная, типа если клиент юрлицо, то передавай одно, если физлицо то другое. Не надо для этих целей городить огород классов. параметризовать маршрут и все на этом.

Comment: @teran Не спорю, уверен там всё проще, я вообще не знаю что там под капотом, но если маршруты дублируются, может и внутри куча всего дублироваться. Так что просто привёл как можно сделать по интересней.

Comment: @teran да, может это для обучения проект или бизнес требования, тут уже автор подскажет.  =) кофе какой-то крепкий оказался и муза пробила, что-то написал к посту текущему